# Retain Browser Scroll Position after visiting one other page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with JS, JQuery, & PHP and trying to do is solve an infinite scroll problem. The problem is that if you scroll for a long way down the page and it loads more pages with ajax, then click a link to go to a new page, how do you automatically go to that same location in the old page when using the browser back button on the new page?

. New pages are loaded on scroll using ajax.

Comment: I wish Facebook would implement that.

Comment: every time your ajax gets new stuff you have to save the current loaded state in a session. then when the user visits some other site and returns to the previous site you just have to load that previous state and scroll to it.

Comment: @ITroubs interesting. So with this type of implementation, do you see any downsides? What if the page has 10,000-15,000 lines of html?

Comment: well that is some kind of a downside. what you could do is just load a certain amount of data where the user was before and if whe wants to "scroll" up you give him the oportunity to "reload" the previous part. (if you know what i mean)

Comment: What about using a script like TurboLinks? https://github.com/rails/turbolinks Though, the bigger question is how do you implement that without ajax loading all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with to my question is to store each page along with relevant data prior to navigating away from the page.

The following information is required to maintain scroll position:

- **Page ID** (unique to page)
- **Page Data** (all of a pages html, careful with data that expires)
- **Paginated Page Number** (Only applies if this page is a feed)
- **Current X, Y scroll position**
- **Timestamp**

When the next page is loaded, the previous information can be stored using local storage. When going back to the previous page, look up the PageID in storage. If it exists, then grab the X or Y coordinate and move page to the position. This takes some strategic thinking because if the page is a lazy-loaded (infinite scroll) type of page or feed, you'll need to have the data already OR be prepared to look up the data based on the position of the page.

The easiest away to build this system is if your whole site is javascript based and you're using the HTML 5 History Api. Preventing full page reloads can help take some of the weight off your server. If you're worried about staying up to date on certain data that expires, you could send the page number to the server and get the respective data to fill in the expired content.

Answer (score -1):

You could get $(window).scrollTop(); value and then save it as a variable in php with the name "pageTop" and call it back on DOM ready:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(window).scrollTo(pageTop);
});
```

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: won't help if you have a facebook like loading of you content and the user is at step 10 of the loading. if you just make a scroll to to the 10th "page" this would fail because it doesn't exist in your html yet

Comment: Edited. I think window.load wait for FB to load. Give it a try.

Comment: This is not usefull until you tell browser to reload all dynamic data before scrolling.

Comment: True, I misread the question. ITroubs comment on the question is the correct way to go.